# Connecting SQL and Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to establish a link between Excel and SQL however I get the following error message "Command text was not set for the command object" when running the VBA code. I'm very new to VBA, can anyone see where I am going wrong please?

FYI I have copied the SQL code in Sheet2.Range("A2")

Here is my VBA code.

```
Sub Update()

Dim link As New ADODB.Connection
Dim login As String
Dim SQLSyntax As String
Dim Basket As New ADODB.Recordset

login = "DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;SERVER=xxxxxx;UID=sa;PWD=xxxxx;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;WSID=PC3;DATABASE=ST_L1;"
SQLSyntax = Sheet2.Range("A2").Text

link.Open login
Basket.Open SQLSyntax, link

Basket.Close
link.Close

End Sub
```

My SQL code (which works fine in SQL).

```
Select P.spn as [Number],P.[Group],P.Name, isnull(T.Calls,0) as [Calls in last 2 months (excluding internals)], isnull(L.[Internal Calls],0) as [Internal Calls] ,isnull(M.[Last call],0)as [Last call] from ST_L1.dbo.Numbers P
left join
(Select COUNT(*)as [Calls],SPN from ST_L1.dbo.Main where CLI not in (Select CLI from ST_L1.dbo.internalCLI)
and start between convert (date,getdate()-62 )and convert (date,getdate())
group by SPN)T on T.SPN = P.spn
left join (Select max(start)[Last call],SPN from ST_L1.dbo.Main
group by SPN)M on M.SPN = P.spn
left join 
(Select COUNT(*)as [Internal Calls],SPN from ST_L1.dbo.Main where CLI in (Select CLI from ST_L1.dbo.internalCLI)
and start between convert (date,getdate()-62 )and convert (date,getdate())
group by SPN)L on L.SPN = P.spn
where LEFT(P.spn,4) not in ('0870') and P.[Group] in 
('BlaBla', 'BlaBla2') 
order by T.Calls asc,M.[Last call]
```

Comment: Which lines returns the error?  Is it `Basket.Open SQLSyntax, link`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, Basket.Open SQLSyntax, link returns the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu never open the recordset?

```
 Set basket = link.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table1;")
```

Comment: Hi @DougCoats thank you for your response. I have replaced `Basket.Open SQLSyntax, link` with `Set Basket = link.Execute(SQLSyntax)` in the above VBA code. It resulted in the same "Command text was not set for the command object" error unfortunately :(

Comment: @ASuperTramp maybe you should parsing the SQL directly in Visual Studio instead of pulling form worksheet? Maybe there is a formatting issues going on.

Comment: This is fixed now. It was a formatting issue. Thank you very much for your help.